# Big Sur and Install msodbcsql17

Tags: php, sqlsrv, macos-big-sur, msodbcsql17

I followed Microsoft's installation for the ODBC PDO driver.

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
brew tap microsoft/mssql-release https://github.com/Microsoft/homebrew-mssql-release
brew update
HOMEBREW_NO_ENV_FILTERING=1 ACCEPT_EULA=Y brew install msodbcsql17 mssql-tools
```

An error occurred installing the extension for PHP.

```
sudo pecl install sqlsrv
sudo pecl install pdo_sqlsrv
```

Error:

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [pdo_sqlsrv.la] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

Does anyone have any ideas or experience with Big Sur?

Comment: I have this exact same problem

Answer (score 2):

For anyone coming across this - you can't currently compile the extensions in Big Sur; however, you can manually download them and install them.

Here are the instructions and issue on Github:

https://github.com/microsoft/msphpsql/issues/1213#issuecomment-730544679

Comment: I recommend you add the contents of the GitHub issue to your answer. Also; it worked like a charm! Thanks for sharing the link!